# Convergence of sequence in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, metric-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ be the set of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ define the following sequence:

\begin{equation}
  f_n(t)=\begin{cases}
               n^{3/2}t\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \textrm{  if }0\le t<1/n\\
               2n^{1/2}-n^{3/2}t\ \ \ \ \textrm{ if }1/n\le t<2/n\\
               0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \textrm{ if } 2/n\le t\le 1
            \end{cases}
\end{equation}

I want to determine whether $f_n$ converges to $0$ in the $d_1-$metric defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
d_1(f,g)=\int_0^1|f(t)-g(t)|dt
\end{equation}

Here is my working:

$f_n$ converges to $0$ if for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $n$ whereby $n>N$ implies that $d_1(f_n,f)<\epsilon$. We compute the integral as follows:

\begin{equation}
\int_0^1f_n(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1/n}n^{3/2}t\ dt+\int_{1/n}^{2/n}2n^{1/2}-n^{3/2}t\ dt=n^{-1/2}.
\end{equation}

Therefore as this decreases to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ we have convergence to zero. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

yes. by the definition if you choose $N=(\frac{1}{\epsilon})^2$. for any $n>N$ we have
$$
n>N \quad \Rightarrow \quad  n^{-1/2} < N^{-1/2}=\epsilon \quad \Rightarrow \quad d(f_n,0)<\epsilon .
$$